# JavaFx draw Image inside in Pane

Tags: java, javafx

Hi I want to drawing image inside in Pane , when a bounds are heigh I want to cut image. This image consists of tile. One tile size is 256. Now my full image is bigger tham Pane. I don't know how I can cut image.
Hi I want to draw one large image, which consists of tiles. One tile has dimensions of 256x256. This image is in Pane. At this time, image dimensions are larger than the dimension Pane. I do not know how to do to draw only in Pane. Thanks for help

```
public class TestURLImage8 {

    public static ArrayList<BusStop2> list = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<PositionTilesAndURLPaths> positionTilesAndURLPathsList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static HashMap<String, Image> imgCache = new HashMap<>();
    public static double lat;
    public static double lon;
    public static double deltaY;
    public static double deltaX;
    public static double positionX;
    public static double positionY;
    public static int[] imageCount = getCountImage();
    public static int [] countImage = countImage();
    public static int []x = new int [countImage[0]];
    public static int []y = new int [countImage[1]];
    private File file = new File("C:/Users/022/workspace22/EkranLCD/res/images/kropka.png");
    private Image bus = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
    static ArrayList<UtlToImageConverter> threadList = new ArrayList<>(); 


    public TestURLImage8(Pane pane) {
    }

    /**
     * Method use to get count of image what we need 
     * @return
     */
    private static int[] getCountImage(){
        int xImageCount = (int) Math.ceil(Main4.width/256);
        int yImageCount = (int) Math.ceil(Main4.height/256);
        return  new int[] {xImageCount, yImageCount};
    }
    /**
     * Method use to get count of tiles
     * @return
     */
    public static int[] countImage(){
        int xImageCount = imageCount[0];
        int yImageCount = imageCount[1];
        if(xImageCount-1 %2 != 0){
            xImageCount = xImageCount + 2;
        }
        if(yImageCount-1 %2 != 0){
            yImageCount = yImageCount + 2;
        }
        return  new int[] {xImageCount, yImageCount};
    }
    /**
     * Method use to get tiles 
     * @param lat
     * @param lon
     * @return
     */
    private static  ArrayList<BusStop2> getTiles(double lat, double lon ){
        int [] numberTile = getTileNumber(lat, lon, Config.mapZoom);
        int a1 = 1;
        int a2 = 1;
        int a3 = 1;
        int a4 = 1;

        x[0] = numberTile[0];
        y[0] = numberTile[1];
          for (int i = 1; i<x.length; i++){
              if(i%2==0){
                  x[i] = numberTile[0]+(a1);
                  a1++;
              }
              else{
                  x[i] = numberTile[0]-(a2);
                  a2++;
              }
          }

          for (int i = 1; i<y.length; i++){
              if(i%2==0){
                  y[i] = numberTile[1]+(a3);
                  a3++;
              }
              else{
                  y[i] = numberTile[1]-(a4);
                  a4++;
              }
          }

          for(int i = 0 ; i<x.length ; i++){
              for (int j = 0 ;j<y.length ; j++ ){
                  list.add(new BusStop2(x[i], y[j], x[0] - x[i], y[0]-y[j]));       
              }
          }
        return list;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param list
     * @return
     */
    private static ArrayList<PositionTilesAndURLPaths> getImgPositionAndURLsPath(ArrayList<BusStop2> list){

        for(BusStop2 bus : list){
            positionTilesAndURLPathsList.add(new PositionTilesAndURLPaths(256*bus.getX(), 256*bus.getY(), 
                    Config.mapPath + "/" + bus.getA() + "/" + bus.getB() + ".png"));
        }
        return positionTilesAndURLPathsList;
    }

     public static int [] getTileNumber(final double lat, final double lon, final int zoom) {
           int xtile = (int)Math.floor( (lon + 180) / 360 * (1<<zoom) ) ;
           int ytile = (int)Math.floor( (1 - Math.log(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(lat)) + 1 / Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat))) / Math.PI) / 2 * (1<<zoom) ) ;
            if (xtile < 0)
             xtile=0;
            if (xtile >= (1<<zoom))
             xtile=((1<<zoom)-1);
            if (ytile < 0)
             ytile=0;
            if (ytile >= (1<<zoom))
             ytile=((1<<zoom)-1);
            return  new int[] {xtile, ytile};
           }

     static double tile2lon(int x, int z) {
         return x / Math.pow(2.0, z) * 360.0 - 180;
      }

      static double tile2lat(int y, int z) {
        double n = Math.PI - (2.0 * Math.PI * y) / Math.pow(2.0, z);
        return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.sinh(n)));
      }

    public void start(Pane pane ,double lat, double lon) throws Exception {
        int [] tiles= getTileNumber(lat, lon, Config.mapZoom);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(Config.xSize, Config.ySize);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(); 
        int [] aa =getTileNumber(lat,lon, Config.mapZoom);
        getTiles(lat,lon); 
        getImgPositionAndURLsPath(list);


        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        ArrayList<UtlToImageConverter2> threadList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for(PositionTilesAndURLPaths url : positionTilesAndURLPathsList){
            threadList.add(new UtlToImageConverter2(url.getPath()));
        }
        try {
            executor.invokeAll(threadList);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(imgCache.size());
        System.out.println( aa[0] + " " + aa[1] );
        deltaX = tile2lon(tiles[0] + 1 , Config.mapZoom) -  tile2lon(tiles[0], Config.mapZoom);
        deltaY = tile2lat(tiles[1], Config.mapZoom) - tile2lat(tiles[1] + 1 , Config.mapZoom);
        positionX = (lon - tile2lon(tiles[0], Config.mapZoom)) * Config.imgSize/deltaX;
        positionY = (tile2lat(tiles[1], Config.mapZoom) - lat) * Config.imgSize/deltaY;

        gc.drawImage(bus,847.0-100 ,621.0-100);
        gc.strokeText("aalala", 847.0-10 ,621.0-10);

        for(PositionTilesAndURLPaths pos : getImgPositionAndURLsPath(list)){
            gc.drawImage(imgCache.get(pos.getPath()),Config.xSize/2-pos.getX()-Config.imgSize/2 ,(Config.ySize/2)- pos.getY()-Config.imgSize/2, Config.imgSize, Config.imgSize);
            System.out.println(pos.getX() + " " + pos.getY());
        }
        gc.drawImage(bus,Config.xSize/2-Config.imgSize/2-Config.markWidth/2+positionX, Config.ySize/2+positionY-Config.imgSize/2-Config.markHeight/2, Config.markWidth, Config.markHeight);
        pane.getChildren().add(canvas);    
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void clear(){
            for(PositionTilesAndURLPaths url : positionTilesAndURLPathsList){
                url = null;
            }
            positionTilesAndURLPathsList.clear();
            threadList.clear();
            for(UtlToImageConverter utl : threadList){
                utl = null;
            }
            for(BusStop2 bus :list){
                bus = null;
            }
            list.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options to display a part of a image in JavaFX:

When using a `Canvas` node, use [the correct `drawImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#drawImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-double-double-double-double-double-double-double-double-), i.e. the one that does not scale the image to the target rectangle. e.g.

```
Rectangle2D rectInSource = ...
Rectangle2D targetRect = ...
gc.drawImage(image,
             rectInSource.getMinX(),
             rectInSource.getMinY(),
             rectInSource.getWidth(),
             rectInSource.getHeight(),
             targetRect.getMinX(),
             targetRect.getMinY(),
             targetRect.getWidth(),
             targetRect.getHeight());
```

Alternatively you could also use a `ImageView` for displaying part of a `Image` by setting the [`viewport` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#viewportProperty) accordingly:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
imageView.setViewport(rectInSource);

// ----------- Only required, if rescaling is desired -----------
imageView.setFitWidth(targetRect.getWidth());
imageView.setFitHeight(targetRect.getHeight());
// --------------------------------------------------------------

imageView.relocate(targetRect.getMinX(), targetRect.getMinY());
pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
```

`rectInSource` denotes the part of the image that should be displayed, `targetRect` the position where it should be drawn.